# Rotating sphere and the velocity of particle at the surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, velocity, angular-velocity

If a sphere is rotating with speed $\omega$ and has a radius $r$, then after one complete revolution what would be the velocity of a particle at the surface (neither at topmost or point of contact of the sphere and the ground) of the sphere? Shouldn't it be zero as the displacement after one complete revolution is zero? Or is it $ωr$?

Comment: The particles on the edge of the sphere have different velocities depending on where they are. Are you talking about instantaneous velocity or average speed?

Comment: I'm referring to the Instantaneous velocity.

Comment: There isn't a single instantaneous velocity for a particle on the surface. This changes depending on what point you are looking at

Answer (score 2):

Velocity is defined as
$$ v = \frac{{\rm d} s}{{\rm d} t}$$
and both differentials have finite values at every time. Hence the current velocity is non-zero at any point of time.
In the equatorial plane, it is ${\rm d} s= r\, {\rm d}\phi$ where $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle. Hence in the equatorial plane it is $v= r \,\frac{{\rm d}\phi}{{\rm d} t} = r \,\omega$ by definition of angular velocity $\omega$.

In general case (in other words in and outside of the equatorial plane, the co-latitude $\theta$ gets important. In this case it is ${\rm d} s= \sin(\theta) \, r \,{\rm d}\phi$ and consequently $v= \sin(\theta) \, r \,\omega$.

The average velocity is the same as the current velocity if $\omega$ and $\theta$ are constant.

Answer (score 0):

After one revolution the

$\text{average velocity} = \dfrac{\text{total displacement }}{\text{time taken}}$

is zero because the the total displacement is zero.

The magnitude of the velocity (speed) will be $r\,\omega$ where $r$ is the distance of the particle from the axis of rotation and $\omega$ the angular speed of the sphere and its direction will be at a tangent to the sphere.

The average speed will also be $r\,\omega$ which is the same as the instantaneous speed because the sphere is rotating at a constant angular speed.

Comment: I want to know about what the velocity would be?

Comment: The total displacement after one revolution is not zero. It is sin(theta) 2 pi r. Consequently, the average velocity after one revolution is (sin(theta) 2 pi r)/(T), where T is the time taken for one revolution.

Comment: Displacement is a vector.  It is the total distance (scalar) which is equal to $2\pi r$.